# Conditional themes in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, themes

Can I have different visual studio themes associated to different solutions?

Here's my problem.
I have two files with sames names that have almost identical contents from two different solutions, open simultaneously. Of course, I have the first solution open and the file from the second solution is opened from explorer and has no connection to the first solution what so ever. 
Is there any way I can distinguish the the file that belongs to the solution from the other file, just by a different tab color or something like that and without hovering over the tab to look up the path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess it can't be done!